# Does this sort exist?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I've been going through some of my old books on algorithms and learning about different kinds of sort.  It looks like all the quickest sorting algorithms run in about O(nLogn) time and it got me thinking about why is this the best we can do?  I wrote another algorithm that appears to run better in certain situations (unless I've missed something), but really badly in other situations.  Is this already an algorithm that is in use and I'm just reinventing the wheel here?

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // array sort looks like it performs best in this example.
    // this is because N is pretty close in value to (max - min) in the array
    int[] arr = { 5, 26, 3, 32, 27, 9, 24, 29, 6, 37, 16, 10, 12, 28, 31, 22, 8, 20, 18, 2, 35, 14, 36, 7, 4, 15, 21};
    arraySort(arr);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }

    // array sort does very poorly here.
    // this is because N is 4 which is very far from the value (max - min = 999) in the array
    int[] arr2 = {1, 1000, 100, 10};
    arraySort(arr2);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr2[i] + " ");
    }

    // I think an algorithm could first check if N and maxDifference are close, then it could
    // make sure that maxDifference is not so big that we start to care about size constraints.
    // If it meets those criteria, we can use arraySort, and if not we can use quicksort.
}

/**
 * Sorts in O(N) + O(maxDifference), where maxDifference is the difference between
 * the maximum and minimum values in the array.  Spatial complexity is an array of
 * size maxDifference.
 */
private static void arraySort(int[] arr) {
    if (arr==null || arr.length ==1){//no need to sort
        return;
    }
    int loopCount = 0;  // used for computing the algorithm's complexity
    int min = arr[0];
    int max = arr[0];
    // get the max and min values
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        loopCount++;
        int element = arr[i];
        if (element < min) {
            min = element;
        } else if (element > max) {
            max = element;
        }
    }
    int maxDifference = max - min;
    // create a boolean array of size maxDifference.
    // spatial complexity can get pretty bad when 
    // there is a huge maxDifference
    boolean[] positions = new boolean[maxDifference + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        loopCount++;
        int element = arr[i];
        // flag this position as true for later traversal
        positions[element - min] = true;
    }

    int count = 0;
    // traverse the array
    for (int i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
        loopCount++;
        boolean element = positions[i];
        if (element) {
            // insert the number into the sorted array
            arr[count++] = i + min;
        }
    }
    int qsortComplexity = (int) (arr.length * Math.log(arr.length)/Math.log(2));
    double isortComplexity = Math.pow(arr.length, 2);
    System.out.println("N = " + arr.length);
    System.out.println("spatial complexity = " + maxDifference);
    System.out.println("complexity = " + loopCount);
    System.out.println("qsortComplexity~= " + qsortComplexity + " isortComplexity~= " + isortComplexity);
}
```

}

**Edit** If anyone's interested I went ahead and modified this to accept duplicates so it's more like counting sort.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // array sort looks like it performs best in this example.
    // this is because N is pretty close in value to (max - min) in the array
    int[] arr = { 5, 26, 3, 32, 27, 9, 24, 29, 6, 37, 16, 10, 12, 28, 31, 22, 8, 20, 18, 2, 35, 14, 36, 7, 4, 15, 21};
    countingSort(arr);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }

    // array sort does very poorly here.
    // this is because N is 4 which is very far from the value (max - min = 999) in the array
    int[] arr2 = {1, 1000, 100, 10};
    countingSort(arr2);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr2[i] + " ");
    }

    // testing duplicates
    int[] arr3 = {10, 10, 9, 5, 6, 6, 4, 3, 7, 4, 10, 5, 3, 8, 2, 9};
    countingSort(arr3);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr3.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr3[i] + " ");
    }

}

/**
 * Sorts in O(N) + O(maxDifference), where maxDifference is the difference between
 * the maximum and minimum values in the array.  Spatial complexity is an array of
 * size maxDifference.
 */
private static void countingSort(int[] arr) {
    if (arr==null || arr.length ==1){//no need to sort
        return;
    }
    int loopCount = 0;  // used for computing the algorithm's complexity
    int min = arr[0];
    int max = arr[0];
    // get the max and min values
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        loopCount++;
        int element = arr[i];
        if (element < min) {
            min = element;
        } else if (element > max) {
            max = element;
        }
    }
    int maxDifference = max - min;
    int[] positionCounts = new int[maxDifference + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        loopCount++;
        int element = arr[i];
        // add to the count at that position
        positionCounts[element - min] +=1;
    }

    int count = 0;
    // traverse the array
    for (int i = 0; i < positionCounts.length; i++) {
        int element = positionCounts[i];
        if (element == 0){
            loopCount++;
        }
        for (int j=0; j<element; j++){
            // insert the number into the sorted array
            arr[count++] = i + min;
            loopCount++;
        }

    }
    int qsortComplexity = (int) (arr.length * Math.log(arr.length)/Math.log(2));
    double isortComplexity = Math.pow(arr.length, 2);
    System.out.println("N = " + arr.length);
    System.out.println("spatial complexity = " + maxDifference);
    System.out.println("complexity = " + loopCount);
    System.out.println("qsortComplexity~= " + qsortComplexity + " isortComplexity~= " + isortComplexity);
}
```

}

Comment: JDK uses Merge sort already which is O(nlogn), well tested, so you are just reinventing the wheel.

Comment: This is indeed counting sort; O(n log n) is the lower bound of _comparison sorting algorithm_, whose only assumption on elements is comparable.

Comment: O(n log n) is the limit for general purpose comparison sorts. It is possible to have sorting algorithms that perform better than O(n log n) for inputs that follow certain restrictions. Heck, insertion sort runs in O(n) if the input is already sorted.

Comment: Sorting cannot be done better than O(nlogn) since the problem itself is Omega(nlogn) problem, when using comparison based sort. More info can be found in [the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Lower_bound_for_the_average_number_of_comparisons)

Comment: Thanks for the wiki link.  I guess because I'm not doing a comparison based sort, but instead I'm placing the values directly into their position in the array I'm getting better than O(nlogn).  Also, yes the inputs need to follow a certain restriction.  I just was wondering if these conditions are checked in common sorting algorithms

Comment: What happens if you have duplicates in your input array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've reinvented a variant [*] of [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

This is not a [comparison sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort) algorithm, so the `Ω(n log n)` lower bound on the worst-case number of comparisons does not apply: this algorithm can indeed run in fewer operations, *provided certain conditions are met*:

- The main condition is that the range of values is limited (and the range is one of the terms in the algorithm's time complexity).
- In the case of your algorithm, another condition is that the elements are unique.

Counting sort and other related algorithms -- such as [bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort), [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) etc -- are useful tools to have in your toolbox. They are not as generally applicable as the likes of quicksort, but can be exactly the right tool in the right circumstances. See Wikipedia for a [comparison of bucket sort with other algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort#Comparison_with_other_sorting_algorithms).

[*] As its name suggests, the classic counting sort *counts* the values instead of using boolean flags, so is more general. Your algorithm cannot correctly deal with duplicate elements: it will lose all but one of them.

Comment: @pickle_inspector: Absolutely. There's no reason not to play with things like that -- it's a great way to learn!

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort), which as you've noticed is a nice solution for collections of items with integer keys whose spread is not significantly larger than the number of elements.

The counting sort is a variant of the bucket sort, using buckets of size 1. This increases the memory requirements of the sort, but reduces the time complexity.